# What's the best way of using gps coordinate in regression model

Tags: python, geolocation, latitude-longitude, transformation, geopandas

In my data set I have two columns for latitude and longitude in decimals and I want to fit the data to a regression model for price prediction. I want know what kind of data transformation I should do on these two columns? Is it possible to just fit the given decimal values to the model or the conversion is required?

I tried converting them to categorical variables using in python geopandas but the mismatching categorical variables in my train and test does not let me to fit the model.

Answer (score 1):

You need the [k-nearest neighbors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-nearest_neighbors_algorithm) (kNN) algorithm, particularly [kNN regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-nearest_neighbors_algorithm#k-NN_regression).

Scikit-learn has two implementation of [kNN regression](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/neighbors.html#nearest-neighbors-regression):

- [KNeighborsRegressor](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.KNeighborsRegressor.html) - Finds the K-neighbors of a point
- [RadiusNeighborsRegressor](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.RadiusNeighborsRegressor.html) - Finds the neighbors within a given radius of a point or points

But of note is the importance of using the [haversine distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula) as their distance metric, which "determines the great-circle distance between two points on a sphere given their longitudes and latitudes," i.e. using the earth's radius.

Additionally, python and scikit-learn expect radian over degrees (lat/lon) so your values must first be converted.

A rudimentary example is as follows:

```
from math import radians
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsRegressor
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

dat['Latitude'] = dat['Latitude'].apply(radians)
dat['Longitude'] = dat['Longitude'].apply(radians)

X = dat[['Latitude', 'Longitude']].values
y = dat['Price'].values

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test \
  = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.25)

nbrs = KNeighborsRegressor(weights='distance', metric='haversine')

nbrs.fit(X_train, y_train)

y_pred = nbrs.predict(X_test)
```